# google maps javascript api long press behaviour is broken down by zoom pinch

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I know that there is no "long press" event in google maps. But i somehow simulated that behaviour using a combination of other events. After pressing some time, a context menu appears with options. However, in devices with support of pinch to zoom such as tablets, after i zoom in or out using two fingers, when i stop touching to device, the menu unexpectedly appears. It is likely that two concurrent touch events disturbs the other one. Anyone with suggestions is appreciated.  Here is the relevant code :

```
        var contextMenuOptions={};
        contextMenuOptions.classNames={menu:'context_menu', menuSeparator:'context_menu_separator'};

        var menuItems=[];
        menuItems.push({className:'context_menu_item', eventName:'start_click', label:'From here'});
        menuItems.push({className:'context_menu_item', eventName:'end_click', label:'To here'});                
        menuItems.push({className:'context_menu_item', eventName:'from_current_loc', label:'From my location'});
        menuItems.push({className:'context_menu_item', eventName:'to_current_loc', label:'To my location'});            
//      menuItems.push({className:'context_menu_item', eventName:'center_map_click', label:'Center map here'});
        contextMenuOptions.menuItems=menuItems; 

        //  create the ContextMenu object
        var contextMenu=new ContextMenu(map, contextMenuOptions);

          google.maps.event.addListener(map, "mousedown", function(event){
                contextMenu.hide();
                sayac = setTimeout(function(){ contextMenu.show(event.latLng); }, 500);                 
          });  
          // main refers to map container
          document.getElementById("main").addEventListener("touchend",function(){ clearTimeout(sayac); });
          document.getElementById("main").addEventListener("touchmove", function(){ clearTimeout(sayac); });
          document.getElementById("main").addEventListener("click",function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the following events to override the tablet events and just do a return inside the handler.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "touchstart", function(e){
    return;
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "touchend", function(e){
    return;
});
```

Here you can read more about the [touchstart](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#the-touchstart-event) and [touchend](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#the-touchend-event) events.

Comment: the solution makes sense but it did not work. Meybe the corresponding event names are different from touchstart and touchend. I could not find any event related to zoom pinch

Comment: Did you try with the event "touchmove"? According to the documentation this event "indicates when the user moves a touch point along the touch surface".

Comment: I also tried it but with no effect, thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: did you try `gesturestart`?

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting on the code i found a workaround, it is not an elegant solution but it works. I edited the following line to include hiding the context menu.

```
document.getElementById("main").addEventListener("touchmove", function(){ clearTimeout(sayac); contextMenu.hide(); });
```